# Karate - How to change text in some html tag

Tags: automated-tests, karate

Using Karate I need change the one string to another in specific html tag. But I am not sure how to do this with Karate (or use some JavaScript). I need this because there is necessity to edit CodeMirror component (https://codemirror.net).

I need to edit/change values between  tags:

```
<span class="cm-string">"https://reservation-api-env-a1.xxx.xxxxx.com"</span>
```

How it is possible to change this using Karate?

Component source code:

[image]

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this just a JS DOM question. I would try something like this.

```
* script('.cm-string', "_.innerHTML = 'foo'"
```

Or please figure out something similar that gets the job done.